# SUBSTR BETWEEN in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Output of the following SQL statement is '279A'

```
    SELECT
    SUBSTR('H0279A',3)
```

I am confused why this query returns 1:

```
        SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN SUBSTR('H0279A',3) BETWEEN '0000' AND '9999'   
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END
```

How can '279A' be between '0000' AND '9999' ?
I am using Teradata.

Comment: why 0000 is enclosed in quotes? I think Between applies to numeric and dates. not to strings.

Comment: I can't tell, since I have gotten this code from a colleauge...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your H0279A is of type varchar. And so is 0000 and 9999. So essentially you are comparing strings and not numbers. 2 comes after 0 and before 9. So its no wonder that 279A is between 0000 and 9999.

Do you want to check whether the given string is between 0 and 9999. Then you should do this.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN SUBSTR('H0279A',3) BETWEEN 0 AND 9999   --here 0 and 9999 are numbers, not strings
           THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END;
```

But this will raise exception, since conversion of 279A to number fails.

**UPDATE:**
Lets keep aside SUBSTR for a while.

```sql
create table ntest(
    col1 varchar(20)
    );

insert into ntest values('abs');
insert into ntest values('abscond');
insert into ntest values('000');
insert into ntest values('000000A');
insert into ntest values('9999');
insert into ntest values('027A');
insert into ntest values('zip');
insert into ntest values('279');
insert into ntest values('279A');
insert into ntest values('877');

select * from ntest order by col1;

col1
-------------------- 
000              <--------------------------¬
000000A                                      |
027A                                         |
279                                          |
279A   -- strings starting with 2 are between strings starting with 0 and 9
877                                          |
9999             <--------------------------⤶
abs
abscond
zip
```

Comment: H0279A is indeed varchar since it is a character code.
The thing that confuses me is how can 'H0279A' be between '0000' AND '9999'... Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: First thing to remember is, you are comparing strings, not numbers. When you open a dictionary where words are sorted, you will find 'apple' first , then 'cat' and 'zoo' last. Similarly, any string starting with '0' will be be first, '2' will come later and '9' last.

Comment: First I thought that I will get "1" as result, if the length of the character string after SUBSTRING function is 4 ie XXXX should always be between '0000' and '9999'. However, even if the string length is less than 4, the query returns 1. Furthermore, I have noticed if the string length is 4 and if the string does not start with numbers but with letters (for example H123), or if the letter is in the first 3 places (fe 1H23 or 12H3) the result is again 0

Comment: do you maybe have some reasonable explanation?

Comment: H123 and 1H23 give 1. 12H3 will give 0, as H3 is clearly outside 0000 and 9999. Go though [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+between+string) posts, maybe they will convince you.

Comment: H123 gives actually 0 and 1H23 and 12H3 gives 1. Furthermore, H3 gives 0 BUT 3H gives 1. Can you please explain why am I getting these outputs?

Comment: maybe because the hierarchy among characters... do you know how can I find which character set Teradata is using and to list the set?

Comment: I think it is like this - if the string starts with a number, then the resut will be 1. If not, it will be 0. Can you confirm that?